# Why we divide arrays till one element in merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

I am reading merge sort algorithm. I have a question

Suppose we have a following list

list = 5 4 1 3 6 8 9 7

First divide list into 4 -4 elements. We call left and right side list

```
5 4 1 3 and 6 8 9 7
```

Then divide 5 4 1 3 into following

```
5 4 and 1 3
```

Then divide 5 and 4 into

```
5 4
```

When sorting we will start sorting from the last step and go till step 1 (where we have 4-4 elements)

Question: Anyways when we divide list till 1-1 elements and we sort and merge list at everymoment then why not divide the list till 4-4 elements only. Because in this case too we will do the merge of the list. Why to iterate till 1-1 element

Comment: The _base case_ occurs when the current iteration has either one or two elements.  When this happens, the algorithm will either return a single element, or sort two elements in place.  This assumes that you are working with a recursive implementation of mergesort, which I assume you are.

Comment: Because an array of only one element is already sorted.

Comment: To clarify Tim Biegeleisen's comment, a bottom up / iterative implementation of merge sort skips all the recursive splitting of an array and starts off by assuming an array of size N is N sub-arrays of size 1. Most real world implementations of merge sort are some variation of bottom up merge sort, such as [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Answer (score 6):

1-element list **is sorted** naturally.
We merge two 1-element sorted lists to get 2-elements sorted list, then merge 2-elements sorted lists to get 4-elements sorted list and so on.

Merge procedure is intended for sorted lists, so we can not apply merge to unsorted `5 4 1 3` and `6 8 9 7` lists

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it's because the merge procedure needs to take two sorted lists. 
A 4-elements list isn't sorted, while a one-element list is.

In practice, we don't split lists to one-element. Because merge sort isn't the most efficient sorting algorithm for small lists, insertion sort is. So the common optimization is to use insertion sort to sort small lists, and merge them with merge sort.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you do it the merge-sort way, there exists an invariant that says that a merged list (after splitting) is sorted, meaning that at every level after merging the splitted lists, the merged lists are ordered.

If you merge right after splitting into 4-4 for instance, will compare the first items of both lists, while both of those values are probably not the smallest values of those splitted lists, meaning you'll end up with a result list that has an ordering that is most likely not sorted.